# Flow to Create a record and relate records to it

Tags: visual-workflow, create-records

I'm working on a flow that'll ask the user for values (text, and picklist values) and create a record and relate existing records to it.

The picklist is a record set of existing records that I need related to the new record. I'm new to flows but I can't seem to get this to work. My searching showed how to do it with triggers but I need to do this 100% in a flow. Any suggestions?

If it matters these are all custom objects

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like what in Flow is known as Dynamic Record Choice.  This is a feature of Visual Workflow that allows you to present records as options that are queried when the flow is run -- in contrast to static options that you hard-code into your Flow, or a options you derive from picklist field configurations.

See the Cloud Flow Designer Guide for more info:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_screen_dynchoice.htm